# Icons are not visible for menu in android studio

Tags: android

I use navigation drawer activity in my code. For certain menu, icons are visible. But for the rest it appears as a shaded square/circle. I tried clean/rebuild/invalidate cache and restart options, still no solution. Any help please...

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/fullstackdeveloper"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_stack"
            android:title="@string/home_label" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/resourceperson"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_person"
            android:title="@string/about_us_label" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/collegeworkshops"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_workshop"
            android:title="@string/portfolio_label" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/tutorials"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_tutorial"
            android:title="@string/contacts_label" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/tutorialvideos"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_video"
            android:title="@string/tutvideos_label" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/scripts"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_script"
            android:title="@string/scripts_label" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/androidapps"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_android"
            android:title="@string/androidapps_label" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/analytics"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_analytics"
            android:title="@string/analytics_label" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/python"
            android:icon="@mipmap/pythonlogo"
            android:title="@string/python_label" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/rprogramming"
            android:icon="@mipmap/rprogramming"
            android:title="@string/rprogramming_label" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/machinelearning"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_machine"
            android:title="@string/machinelearning_label" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/booking"
            android:icon="@mipmap/contacts"
            android:title="@string/booking_label" />


    </group>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where is Your **`Code`**

Comment: can you please share screen short of your app

Comment: refer code above

Comment: @Elackya share the code of **`NavigationView`** xml with question

Comment: can you please check my ans ?

Comment: @KaushalGosaliya: screenshot added

Comment: @Shambhu: already posted

Comment: @jeetparmar: ok

Comment: unfortunately it's worked in my code but i  m totally surprised why noy worked in your code ?

Comment: please view the updated screenshot. one menu has a icon. but why it is not working for the rest ?

Comment: @jeetparmar: it's ok.. I will try for alternate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are following material design stander while creating icon for menu.
If you follow then it will show icons otherwise not.
You can confirm this by setting following icon

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
```

You will see this icon in your drawer.

Above suggestion is 1 way to show icon in drawer other way is what @jeetparmar has suggest in above answer you can follow that also.

Comment: I am asking about material design stander for Icons(job of designer) not in android code, is it so?

Comment: Designer or person who has created icons need to create icon as per android material design guidelines(icon height,width,padding etc) see
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85080/material-design-icon-size-in-navigation-drawer/85083

Comment: I believe I created icons as per the standard. please refer my code above and suggest me if any changes required

Comment: So only option left with you is follow answer given by @jeetparmar in your post

Comment: Can you pl try by adding icons in drawable folder?

Comment: Generally we use mipmap for launcher icons or app icons

Comment: thank u so much.. it worked. I added icons in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Home"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/home_item"
        tools:ignore="MenuTitle" />
</group>
```

==========home_item============

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/HOME"
    android:textColor="@color/colorblack"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:alpha="0.3"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:src="@mipmap/right_arrow"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp">

</ImageView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_22sdp"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do I have to create separate layout file for each menu ?